# Prevent android studio to create more than a tag in xml files

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, auto-generate

In the new android studio 3.3 or 3.2 if we create a for example button auto generate create a text like

```
<Button android:layout_width="" android:layout_height=""/>
```

but I would like something more like this

```
<Button 
        android:layout_width="" 
        android:layout_height=""/>
```

like old versions of Android studio is there a setting or something for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is related to `XML` code `wrapping`. By default it should be on `wrap always` but maybe it's not in your `Android Studio` or they changed that in newer versions. Anyway you can find that by click on:

**Preferences -> Code Style (expand it) -> XML -> Android(Tab) ->** 
Here you can find `Layout Files` and below options like: `Wrap always`, `Don't wrap`, `Wrap if long` etc. So set it on `Wrap always` and `Apply` changes and your `XML` code from now on should be wrapped.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It hints something that says reduce intent with 4 spaces. Try to configure that :)
Or use the hard way by pressing **enter** for the new row.